# Cloud9 ajax call between two workspaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cross-domain, cloud9-ide

I am tring to set up my Cloud9 workspace to work on a rails api projet. The repo contain 2 projects, the rails json api and the front (angular app).

As cloud9 does not provide two external ports, i cannot run them both on the same workspace.
I created 2 differents workspaces, one running the rails api and the other running the angular app (served by a small node process).

Everything is fine except that when i try to call the api (ajax call => $http), i get a cross origin request warning.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://workspace-user.c9.io/. The request was redirected to 'https://c9.io/api/nc/auth?response_type=token&client_id=proxy&redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fworkspace-user.c9.io%2F', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

How can i prevent that?

Thank you

ps: The real url is not workspace-user,  i did change it.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say your domains are:

```
https://ws1-user.c9.io (page which performs ajax is located here) 
https://ws2-user.c9.io  (destination url)
```

In ws2-user.c9.io open the terminal and write:

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-cloud9.conf
```

add the following line:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://ws1-user.c9.io"
```

In the terminal write:

```
sudo a2enmod headers
service apache2 restart
```

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which sites are allowed to connect using special CORS headers. For more information see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS